# Azure functions table binding with filter query

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

Filter query currently throwing an exception when attempting to retrieve a list that match the query

The documentation implies its OData, putting an oData string in doesn't fix it

```
public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *", RunOnStartup =true)] TimerInfo myTimer,
         [Table("MyService", Connection = "TableStorage", Filter = "Active eq 1", Take = 10)] IEnumerable<LogEntity> myTable,
        ILogger log)
```

Active is a numeric column in my table.

Error:

Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Test'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Tables: Can't bind Table to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Test.LogEntity]'.

Comment: Please edit your question and include code for your entity class.

Answer (score 0):

**When I tried with your code, I got the same error.**

[image]

Instead, If your function is In-process Azure function, you can use `TableClient` to read the table by using Azure SDK.

```cs
 public static class Function1
        { 
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
            public static async Task RunAsync([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, [Table("Table_Name", Connection = "storage_connection_string")] TableClient tableClient, ILogger log)
            {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
            AsyncPageable<LogEntity> queryResults = tableClient.QueryAsync<LogEntity>(filter: $"PartitionKey eq 'Pk1' and RowKey gt 'pr'");
            await foreach (LogEntity entity in queryResults)
            {
                log.LogInformation($"{entity.PartitionKey}\t{entity.RowKey}\t{entity.Timestamp}");
            }
        }
```

**function.json**

```cs
{

"generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Generator-4.1.1",

"configurationSource": "attributes",

"bindings": [

{

"type": "timerTrigger",

"schedule": "0 */5 * * * *",

"useMonitor": true,

"runOnStartup": false,

"name": "myTimer"

},

{

"type": "table",

"connection": "connectionstringname of storage connection string in local.settings.json",

"tableName": "Table_Name",

"name": "tableClient"

}

],

"disabled": false,

"scriptFile": "../bin/FunctionApp37.dll",

"entryPoint": "FunctionApp37.Function1.RunAsync"

}
```

- If you are using **Isolated Azure functions**, you can use `FILTER` and `TAKE`.
- Follow the [MSDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table-input?tabs=isolated-process,table-api&pivots=programming-language-csharp#example%5C) to configure Azure functions Table binding with filter.

**References:**

[Azure Tables input bindings for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table-input?tabs=in-process%2Ctable-api&pivots=programming-language-csharp#example)